# Export .csv using java.io.FileOutputStream

Tags: csv, fileoutputstream

I am trying to export a in JavaScript-generated CSV-file to a path (e. g. "C:/ExportedDocuments/") using the java.io.FileOutputStream. However, I guess something is missing or wrongfully defined in my Code, as I am receiving an Error message that I am trying to use a method which doesn't exist. As it was mentioned in the comments section, I am most likely passing the CSV wrongfully to the FileOutputStream. But I don't know, how to do it correctly.

The Code is running as a Workflow-Script.

Here is my Code:

```
var data = [
   ['Audi', 'A8'],
   ['VW', 'Golf R'],
   ['BMW', 'M3']
];

var csv = 'Brand,Model';
  data.forEach(function(row) {
      csv += row.join(',');
      csv += "\n";
});

outputStream = new java.io.FileOutputStream("C:/ExportedDocuments/" + "textfile" + ".csv");
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(csv, outputStream);
outputStream.close();
```

That's the Error:

> Exporting failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: None of the fixed
>   arity signatures [(java.io.InputStream, java.io.OutputStream),
>   (java.io.Reader, java.io.Writer), (java.io.InputStream,
>   java.io.Writer), (java.io.Reader, java.io.OutputStream)] of method
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy match the argument types
>   [jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ConsString, java.io.FileOutputStream]

Comment: if you are a total beginner, I recommend for you to begin at the beginning. first learn the basics, and don't go into more advanced material until you have a  solid knowledge of those

Comment: most likely because you pass different type of parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a ByteArrayInputStream. This is the working solution:

```
var data = [
   ['Audi', 'A8'],
   ['VW', 'Golf R'],
   ['BMW', 'M3']
];

var csv = 'Brand,Model';
  data.forEach(function(row) {
      csv += row.join(',');
      csv += "\n";
});

var CSVStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(csv.getBytes("UTF-8"));

outputStreamcsv = new java.io.FileOutputStream("C:/ExportedDocuments/" + "name" + ".csv");
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(CSVStream, outputStreamcsv);
outputStreamcsv.close();
```